# Thoughts on character Leitmotifs?

Tags: music

Specific thoughts on character [Leitmotifs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif).

For those who are confused, a Leitmotif is a usually simple piece of music used to represent a character, and is often played to signify that it's, well, them! For example movies and video games use them as character themes.

I was wondering thoughts on it regarding fleshing out characters for writing purposes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's hard to get a handle on precisely what you're looking for, so people are at a loss for how to answer. Do you have a specific experience that sparked this question? Context would give us something to focus our answers on. Also, please read our [faq](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq); it might be helpful.

Comment: It's as BESW said, but additionally, simply asking for arbitrary opinions isn't really a good fit for this site. Do read the FAQ; [this part](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) describes what you should steer clear of - and what your question unfortunately currently appears to be!

Comment: I think there is a great question here.  Can you defined what your problem/issue is more tightly?  A good rule is that things asking for lists, discussions, or that are too general cannot have a "best" answered and thus will be closed.  What are you trying to solve?  Are you unsure how to use the leifmtifs, whether they are a good idea, or how to define one?

Comment: @Sardathrion Although "close" sounds rather final, one purpose of the vote-to-close option is to protect a question while it's being formed, so that answers which will ultimately fail to apply to the question's final form don't needlessly accrue. When the question is edited, it'll be quickly re-opened. So far as I can see, the question has not been downvoted --which would indicate disapproval rather than simply considering the question nascent.

Comment: Rather than ask for thoughts, could you perhaps ask the more detailed question to the effect of "how do I choose of develop a character leitmotiff?" or "Is developing a leitmotiff a good idea for an RPG character?"

Comment: Flagged as not a real question. If you retool it to be something like: How do character leitmotifs played during gameplay help roleplay and are there any side-effects/negative implications? then I think you'll have a good fit for the site. Basically RPG.SE is in a Q & A style.  Welcome to the community!

Comment: @ClockworkTower: Do not be discouraged by your question being closed.  It is not a permanent state.  Look at all the comments, re-frame your question, and you will have a very good and worthwhile question.  To be honest, if you leave this as is, I might ask a question about leitmotiff myself -- however, I want you to get the rep!  ^_~